# Hyperref causing warning with table of contents, list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, warnings

I receive the following warning and managed to figure out that these were due to some interplay between the `hyperref` package and the commands `\tableofcontents`, `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` (the command `\afterpreface` essentially does `\tableofcontents`, `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`). I have `\hyperref` package as the last package added in my preamble and with the following options:

`\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}`

How do I get rid of these warnings?

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/omslmr.fd)pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination wit
h the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125   \afterpreface
                     [1] (./temp.toc)pdfTeX warning (ext4): destina
tion with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ig
nored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125   \afterpreface
                     [2] (./temp.lot)pdfTeX warning (ext4): destina
tion with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ig
nored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125   \afterpreface
                     [3] (./temp.lof
Underfull \vbox (badness 2189) has occurred while \output is activepdfTeX warni
ng (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already 
used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.12 ...sponds to $10^4$ sec/m.}}{28}{figure.2.10}
                                                   [4])pdfTeX warning (ext4): d
estination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplic
ate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.125   \afterpreface
                     [5]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identi
fier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are using something like `\pagenumbering{gobble}`. Since the page number is also used for destinations and page labels. If you want to suppress the page number on pages that automatically set page style `plain` (page that starts the chapter/table of contents/...) then you can redefine the page style `plain` as described in section "7 Redefining `plain` style" in the [documentation for package `fancyhdr`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
```

For other pages (title page, ...) page style `empty` can be used.
Also the page anchors can be disabled by `\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}` and reenabled by using `true`.